# python: how to kill Excel session in separate thread after timeout?

Tags: python, pywin32

I am executing an Excel macro in python and would like to kill it after timeout. However, existing timeout and kill Excel process method are not working for me. Can you please help?

```
import threading
import win32com.client as win;
import pythoncom;

Excel = None;
workbook = None;

def worker(e):
    global Excel;
    global workbook;

    pythoncom.CoInitialize();    
    Excel = win.DispatchEx('Excel.Application');
    Excel.DisplayAlerts = False;
    Excel.Visible = True;
    workbook = Excel.Workbooks.Open("sample.xlsm", ReadOnly = True);
    Excel.Calculation = -4135;
    print "Run";
    Excel.Run('Module2.Refresh');

e = threading.Event()
t = threading.Thread(target=worker, args=(e,));
t.start()

# wait 5 seconds for the thread to finish its work
t.join(5)
if t.is_alive():
    print "thread is not done, setting event to kill thread."
    e.set();
    print "1";
    workbook.Close();
    print "2";
    Excel.Quit();
else:
    print "thread has already finished."
    workbook.Close();
    Excel.Quit();
```

I got error:

```
Run
thread is not done, setting event to kill thread.
1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "check_odbc.py", line 62, in <module>
    workbook.Close();
  File "C:\Users\honwang\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\py27_32\lib\site-package
s\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 527, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError("%s.%s" % (self._username_, attr))
AttributeError: Open.Close
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it is not possible to kill threads. All you can do is ask them nicely to suicide, then hope for the best. Just passing an event object is not enough, you have to actively check for that event inside the thread and suicide when it is set. Since your thread is blocked while running excel code it can't check for the event - that means you can yell at it to suicide as much as you want but there's no code to make it listen.

If you need this kind of parallelism on inherently blocking code, I strongly suggest you use processes instead, because those can be killed. Otherwise if possible use asynchronous programming.